# Localhost confirming but not sending account verification code using gmail smtp server

Tags: php

This is how sendmail.ini is scripted. This is followed with the parameters as defined in the sendmail.ini file.  If you may let me know what mistake I am making. Thanks

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=mymail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypass
force_sender=mymail@gmail.com
```

And here is how mail related parameters have been defined in php.ini file:

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587

sendmail_from = mymail@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.force_extra_parameters = mymail@gmail.com
```

Comment: This line looks wrong `sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`